# android webview copy url with Long Press

Tags: android

I'm making a WebView app
I'm trying to do this

```
    view.loadurl("example.com" ) 

    on Longpress 

If domain = example.com 
Then copy url Link
If domain is not example.com
Then Do Nothing
    ---------

    Then do Something
```

Is this possible ?

i have no idea how to start ?

**Sorry For Bad English**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
For detecting long press within web view, you can check this [Getting selected text in a WebView via a contextual action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856362/getting-selected-text-in-a-webview-via-a-contextual-action-bar)

Comment: do i really create button ? , i don't show any button in webview.. hmm maybe i can set button.view.invible ?

Comment: thanks nighthawk24 , for now this funtion is achived :( , will make this funtion in pro version .. if i'll be able to do thanks bro again

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at something like [this](http://androidbite.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/android-long-press-event-handle-example.html) and learn the key concepts of android events. Also pseudo isn't really ideal, much more informative to post actual Java code.