# getSelection text in android with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, range

How do you select text in Android and detect Android browser with Javascript?

One example:

```
<script>
function select(){
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    alert(sel);
}
</script>

<div onmouseup="select();">

it is a example 

<div>
```

Are functions on range compatible with Android?

Comment: Does that code not work on Android browsers?

Comment: I've tried and I think it dont works. I update it

Comment: yes, I try this on my android 2.3 and it not works

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892111/android-webview-javascript-getselection)

Comment: oh! get me the url of the post, please.