# Highlight Text feature like google play book

Tags: android, select, text, webview

I want my android application to have text highlighting within a `WebView`. Similar to the functionality found in Google play book. Does any one have an idea how to achieve this?

I'm using a `WebView` because my content is in html form.

basically talking about this effect:

[image]

Comment: yaa. i was talking about this..So ny help

Comment: you want highlight text while selecting or when?

Comment: while selecting. i am using web view now because my content is in html form. but cant achieve this on web view. any other option

Comment: @SuhailMehta : have you found any working approach on this ? I am looking for similar features to provide in my Textview or Webview which is going to display HTML .

Answer (score 0):

*The blue selection you see is part of the standard android environment when selecting text. So that should work on your standard webview without need of any custom code.* => I'm no longer convinced this is true. Looks like it's not.

The green (yellow, orange, red, ...) selection however is custom.

**You could read out the selected text from your selection event and use that information to update the html content, wrap the text in a span with a background color set.**

Alternative approach is using javascript and enabling javascript in your webview. Not sure however how to get that done.

Some sources to check for that approach are https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection and [Android: How to select text from WebView, and highlight it onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972857/android-how-to-select-text-from-webview-and-highlight-it-onclick)

**Text selection from WebView details**

To get the text selection working on a `WebView` you can use the following snippet ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)). Trigger this on a button click (or other event) from your (context) menu.

```
private void emulateShiftHeld(WebView view)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                                                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
            shiftPressEvent.dispatch(view);
            Toast.makeText(this, "select_text_now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("dd", "Exception in emulateShiftHeld()", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u be more specific on selection event

Comment: I've updated the question with some more detail. Apparently it's not as default as I thought it was. Looks like even the selection needs some custom code. Example added to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from API level 11, you can use [`TextView`'s `textIsSelectable` flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#isTextSelectable%28%29).

---

Edit: Even though the question has now been edited to specifically mention `WebView`, OP @Suhail's comment "my content is in html form" does not fully disqualify `TextView` as it can also render some basic HTML.

Comment: how do you see this combined with the webview in this use case?

Comment: @hcpl question does not specify context, e.g. `WebView` or `TextView`

Comment: indeed, I'll add a correction for that. It's only mentioned in the comments of the question that this is for a webview.

Answer (score 0):

If your using WebView Try to integrate Mozilla  PDF.JS where you can render PDF . which can contain Images also .